# Do heroes need to spend hero points on advantages and backgrounds gained when using the Destiny Spread?

Tags: 7th-sea

The 7th Sea nation books introduced the "Destiny Spread"... A way of generating a set of random advantages, backgrounds, and arcana to build a character around.

The rules have this to say, regarding cost:

> If you choose your Strength, your Hero gains the Virtue corresponding to that card, and you pay 10 HP for performing the Destiny Spread. If you choose your Weakness, your Hero gains the Hubris corresponding to that card, and you gain 10 extra HP to build your Hero with. Finally, consult the Past, Present, and Future charts to see what your Hero gained (or lost!) from those draws.

When I read this, I see two interpretations:

- You pay for whatever you get from the Destiny Spread (including 10HP for a virture, or -10HP for a Hubris... The standard costs).
- Alternatively, the rules say "you pay 10 HP [or -10 HP later on] for performing the Destiny Spread." This seems to imply that you're getting a package deal for either 10 HP (Virtue package) or -10 HP (Hubris package), regardless of whatever else you get.

Does anyone know which interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the extras are free - much like the old heritage charts in L5R 1e.